# Allow others to view repo w/o being added as collaborators

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to allow others to view a private repo on GitHub without adding them as collaborators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through Organisations, this way it's in read only.

---

**Resources:**

- [Github - Read-only access to private repo](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/3923-read-only-access-to-private-repo)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, repo permissions are all or nothing.